# ByteArray insertion in MarkLogic using "temporal.documentInsert" inserts but returns twice the count of ByteArray?

Tags: arrays, marklogic, temporal

Have inserted into MarkLogic using [`temporal.documentInsert`](https://docs.marklogic.com/temporal.documentInsert) by passing `ByteArray` of count `5000`, but after insertion when retrieving the data using `cts.doc` it returns the `ByteArray` count as `10000` (double the actual initial value).

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Can you post some example code that you are using? It helps to provide a minimum, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I can find nothing referencing 'ByteArray's in the docs.
What did you use to get the 'count' of the document ?
My guess is that there is a byte -> char conversion, 
Java chars are 16 bits (2 bytes).  Depending on the encoding, 
which will occur both on insert and on get -- in the java JVM,
and exactly which java API you used to get 'count' (count of what?)
an exact 2x difference is suspiciously identical to a byte -> char conversion in java.
If you convert your document to a String, what is the *string* length (in chars),
for the input and output documents, as seen in Java, using String.length,
and using an explicit charset for conversion.